# how Android parse manifest file after installing an application?

Tags: android, parsing, android-manifest

Can someone share with me the steps executed by the `Android` OS on an newly downloaded APK for its bundled `AndroidManifest` file?
Actually I keen to know that what does `Android` OS do after downloading and before confirming installation successful. how it reads the `AndroidManifest` and whats the sequence of that...?

Comment: you should try to be more specific about your query - `downloaded APK for its bundled AndroidManifest file?`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Install time parsing

`PackageManager` is a system component that runs on Android devices (in `system_server`) and plays a key role in the installation process, and the one that concerns itself with parsing the `AndroidManifest.xml` file of the package being installed.

Precisely the parsing is happening in [PackageParser.java](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/content/pm/PackageParser.java).

**UPDATE:**

While on Android R [PackageParser.java](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/content/pm/PackageParser.java) still remains in place and contains the code for parsing, that code is effectively "deprecated" in favour of  [ParsingPackageUtils.java](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/content/pm/parsing/ParsingPackageUtils.java)

#### Build time parsing

There is also another parsing of the `AndroidManifest.xml` that happens when Android package file (`.apk`) is being built. When the [aapt2 (Android Asset Packaging Tool)](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/aapt2) links compiled resource files it also takes, parses and validates the `AndroidManifest.xml` file. This happens in [ManifestFixer.cpp](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/tools/aapt2/link/ManifestFixer.cpp). It also parses the `AndroidManifest.xml` extracted from an `.apk` file when `aapt2 dump badging` or `aapt2 dump permissions` are executed - [DumpManifest.cpp](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/tools/aapt2/dump/DumpManifest.cpp)

Answer (score -1):

Actually you could find more directly in android source code:

```
$ find sdk/sdkmanager/* -name "*Manifest*.java"
sdk/sdkmanager/libs/sdklib/src/com/android/sdklib/xml/AndroidManifest.java
sdk/sdkmanager/libs/sdklib/src/com/android/sdklib/xml/ManifestData.java
sdk/sdkmanager/libs/sdklib/src/com/android/sdklib/xml/AndroidManifestParser.java
sdk/sdkmanager/libs/sdklib/tests/com/android/sdklib/xml/AndroidManifestParserTest.java
```

`ManifestData.java` is quite important, and acts a fundamental role, recommend you to read further.

Appendix: this directory has four java source codes:

```
$ ls sdk/sdkmanager/libs/sdklib/src/com/android/sdklib/xml/
AndroidManifest.java        AndroidXPathFactory.java
AndroidManifestParser.java  ManifestData.java
```